# Why are zeroes of the elliptic curve (mod p) for integer values symmetrical about p/2

Tags: elliptic-curves

I've been reading about the elliptic curve used for key generation in bitcoin ie y^2 = x^3 + 7 (mod p) [I'm not sure how to do the congruence symbol]

To help me visualise whats going on I wrote a script to plot the values of y * y - (x * x * x + 7) (mod p) as colours (black = 0).

This is the result where p = 5

[image: mod 5]

The plot is NOT symmetrical about y=p/2 but when I mark the integer values of x and y (the red dots) which yield a zero solution the result IS symmetrical (for all values of p)

Is there a neat mathematical reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First view the curve over $ℝ$. The equation
$$E: Y^2 = X^3 + 7$$
has solutions clearly symmetrical about the horizontal axis $Y = 0$ because any real point $(x,y)$ solves the equation if and only if $(x,-y)$ does.

The very same is happening modulo $n$ for any integer $n$. The difference is that modulo $n$, you have $-y \equiv n-y$ for all integers $y$, which gives you *another* axis of symmetry. For every integer point $(x,y)$ and modulo $n$
$$(x,y) ∈ E  ⇔  (x,-y) ∈ E  ⇔ (x,n-y) ∈ E.$$

This now looks like a symmetry about the line $Y = \dfrac n 2$.

For example, for $n = 5$, you get the symmetries
\begin{align*}(3,2) ∈ E  ⇔ (3,-2) ∈ E  ⇔ (3,3) ∈ E,\\
(4,1) ∈ E  ⇔ (4,-1) ∈ E  ⇔ (4,4) ∈ E.
\end{align*}

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. I was confused as to why the same logic wouldn't apply to other values of x,y in R (I expected the whole plot to be symmetrical about y=n/2) but of course the symmetry only applies to *integer* values (because the modulus is an integer) of x,y that *satisfy the elliptic equation* (the zeroes of my plot). It's an odd result when you look at the plot but I understand it now. Thanks.